# Exception...NoReverseMatch ...Reverse for 'venue' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['venue/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to develop a Django app for a booking system. I know the problem is from the url link pk argument that was passed to the venues.html. I've tried everything possible to solve this problem and nothing has worked. In venues.html, I've tried
`<li><a href="{% url 'booking:venue' pk %}">v.venue</a></li>`
`<li><a href="{% url 'booking:venue' pk=v.pk %}">v.venue</a></li>` - This shows me a list of all my venues as v.venue and only the first integer works (I hope this makes sense).
`<li><a href="{% url 'booking:venue' 1 %}">v.venue</a></li>`- This shows a result similar to the previous one I just mentioned.
Every other argument I've tried has given me the same error...

I've read the django documentation on class-based detailview and watched and read a number of tutorials but nothing has helped. From everything I've found, the code I've written is supposed to work...
However, I keep getting this traceback error. Pls, I would really appreciate any help I can get. Thank you so much.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/venues/

Django Version: 3.1.6
Python Version: 3.8.8
Installed Applications:
['booking',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\Ada Eloka\OneDrive\python_work\space_pau\booking\templates\booking\base.html, error at line 6
   Reverse for 'venue' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['venue/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']
   1 : <p>
   2 :   <a href="{% url 'booking:home' %}">PAU SPACE MANAGEMENT</a> -
   3 :   <a href="{% url 'booking:venues' %}">Venues</a>
   4 : </p>
   5 : 
   6 : {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
   7 : 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ada Eloka\OneDrive\python_work\space_pau\sp_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Ada Eloka\OneDrive\python_work\space_pau\sp_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\Ada Eloka\OneDrive\python_work\space_pau\sp_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\Ada Eloka\OneDrive\python_work\space_pau\sp_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "C:\Users\Ada Eloka\OneDrive\python_work\space_pau\sp_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Ada Eloka\OneDrive\python_work\space_pau\sp_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Ada Eloka\OneDrive\python_work\space_pau\sp_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Ada Eloka\OneDrive\python_work\space_pau\sp_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Ada Eloka\OneDrive\python_work\space_pau\sp_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Ada Eloka\OneDrive\python_work\space_pau\sp_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Ada Eloka\OneDrive\python_work\space_pau\sp_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Ada Eloka\OneDrive\python_work\space_pau\sp_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Ada Eloka\OneDrive\python_work\space_pau\sp_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Ada Eloka\OneDrive\python_work\space_pau\sp_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Ada Eloka\OneDrive\python_work\space_pau\sp_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Ada Eloka\OneDrive\python_work\space_pau\sp_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Ada Eloka\OneDrive\python_work\space_pau\sp_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "C:\Users\Ada Eloka\OneDrive\python_work\space_pau\sp_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Ada Eloka\OneDrive\python_work\space_pau\sp_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\Ada Eloka\OneDrive\python_work\space_pau\sp_env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Ada Eloka\OneDrive\python_work\space_pau\sp_env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /venues/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'venue' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['venue/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']
```

**This is what my views. py looks like:**

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, DetailView
from booking.models import Venue, Booking


class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'booking/home.html'
    
class VenueListView(ListView):
    model = Venue
    template_name = 'booking/venues.html'
        
class VenueDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Booking
    template_name = 'booking/venue.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(VenueDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

**urls.py:**

```
"""Defines URL patterns for booking."""

from django.urls import path

from .views import HomePageView, VenueListView, VenueDetailView

app_name = 'booking'

urlpatterns = [
    # Home page
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('venues/', VenueListView.as_view(), name='venues'),
    path('venue/<int:pk>', VenueDetailView.as_view(), name='venue'),
]
```

and

**venues.html:**

```
{% extends "booking/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Venues</h2>
  <ul>
    {% for v in object_list %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'booking:venue' pk %}">v.venue</a></li>
    {% empty %}
      <li>No venues.</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endblock content %}
```

**venue.html:**

```
{% extends "booking/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <h2>Venue: {{booking.venue}}</h2>
  
  <p>Details</p>
  
  <p>{{booking.event}}</p>
  <p>{{booking.preferred_date}}</p>
  
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: venues.html `"{% url 'booking:venue' pk %}"` -> `"{% url 'booking:venue' v.pk %}"`

Comment: It still doesn't work. Still lists my 2 venues as v.venue and v.venue and when I click on the first v.venue it shows me details of the 1st venue and when I click on the 2nd v.venue it shows me a page not found (404) error

Comment: @AdaEloka `v.venue` should be `{{ v.venue }}`... Also your urls should always end in a trailing slash `'venue/<int:pk>'` -> `'venue/<int:pk>/'`. Also only the first one works because your `DetailView` is not for the model `Venue` while you pass it a pk belonging to a venue.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you so much! That was what I was missing! I can't believe it...I'm literally crying! As for the `DetailView` not being for the model `Venue` I'll look into it and try to figure it out and if I run into problems I'll ask again. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey @AbdulAzizBarkat. I solved the 2nd problem of using the correct model for the `DetailView`. So now everything works fine. Thanks a lot!